# How to write a query to get only first matching row while joining two tables?

Tags: sql, database, sybase, inner-join

Consider I have following tables:

**Table 1:**

```
AId
AMoniker
```

**Table2:**

```
BId
BMoniker
```

*Table1->Table2 is one to many relationship*

I want a temp table out of these two tables where if a particular Amoniker has multiple BMonikers then only first one should go in the table.

For example, if tables have following data:

**Table1:**

```
1 ABCD
2 DEFG
3 QWER
```

**Table 2:**

```
1 QZ
1 XC
1 CV
2 DE
2 OP
3 QW
```

the query should return the following:

```
ABCD QZ
DEFG DE
QWER QW
```

My query to get all the rows is:

```
select b.BMoniker, a.AMoniker
into #moniker_map
from Table1 a inner join Table2 b
on a.Aid=b.Bid
```

How can i modify this to get only 1st row from Table2 for each Id.

I tried following query:

```
select b.BMoniker, a.AMoniker
from Table1 a inner join Table2 b
on a.Aid=b.Bid
and b.BMoniker in 
(
    select top 1 BMoniker
    from Table2
    where Bid=cb.Bid
    ORDER BY BMoniker
)
```

But i get following error:
Incorrect syntax near keyword 'top'
Sybase error code = 156, SQLState="ZZZZZ"

Comment: You'll have to define "first" row. Which one? What order?

Answer (score 2):

Selects row with minimum value from table2 (PostgreSQL syntax):

```
SELECT a.AMoniker, MIN(b.BMoniker) FROM Table1 a, Table2 b
WHERE a.Aid = b.Bid GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a typo but it looks like your subquery is referencing an table alias cb which is not defined. Can you try this:

```
select b.BMoniker, a.AMoniker
from Table1 a inner join Table2 b
on a.Aid=b.Bid
and b.BMoniker in 
(
    select top 1 BMoniker
    from Table2 c
    where c.Bid=a.Bid
    ORDER BY BMoniker
)
```